# How to trigger re-render when using stateless functional components in react starter kit

Tags: react-starter-kit

I am building an app using [react starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).  In past react apps, I had always triggered incremental re-rendering of DOM elements by using react.setState.

What is the best practice to re-render dom elements based on changes in state when using the stateless function component pattern used by this starter kit?